# Show delete button inside row of a ListView when clicking a button Android

Tags: java, android

I need to implement a kind of Slide to Delete inside my `ListView` but what I want is not to slide the row but when the user clicks a button inside the row the delete button should show up. Is it possible? I've already implemented the `Button` and I know when the user press it but I pretty much have no idea on how to implement the delete button slide in effect from the right of the row.
Can someone give me an Idea on how to start?

Comment: follow https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Swipe-to-delete, then the implementation is pretty simple.

Basically you are gonna show/hide that button on button click.

Since Android ListView reuses the Views, if you show/hide the button of a View of ListItem in onItemClick(), then when the list is scrolled the state will be lost and will result in incorrect behavior.

So we need to maintain this selection state in the Adapter's modal class. Just add a field like selected in the modal class. For instance, if you are showing list of **Contact** objects, then your modal class will be all like,

```
class Contact {

  private String name;

  private String number;

  private boolean selected;

  ..........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I've understand; you need to implement lets say an edit button, then when user clicks on it, it will disappear and another button called delete will popup instead of it on the same position.

here is a possible  approach to achieve that:

in your `list_view_adapter.xml`:

1-create a frame layout contain both of the buttons on top of each other.

2-default state of delete button is GONE -> android:visibility="gone"

3-when edit is pressed delete button will be visible and you will programmatically set `Edit` visibility to `GONE`

4-set your delete button:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    // Some other things...

    Button delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       // After you delete the object from Parse database here,
       notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```